# Why can't it convert to a double or int or string from Car_Management.Car

Tags: c#, variable-assignment

I am running through a problem where I receive an error saying that I cannot convert from 'double' to 'Car_Management.Car'. What am I missing here? Here are my codes I have done so far where I have to add the car characteristics to a list. Also, how may I output the list to a text file?

```
namespace Car_Management
{
    class CarDM
    {
        public static void save(List<Car> fullList)
        {
            Car myCar = new Car();
            List<Car> list = new List<Car>() {myCar.Model, myCar.Mileage, myCar.Colour, myCar.Year};

            StreamWriter outputFile;
            outputFile = File.CreateText("List.txt");
        }
        public static void load()
        {
            StreamReader inputFile;
            inputFile = File.OpenText("List.txt");
        }
    }
}
```

This is my other class

```
namespace Car_Management
{
    class Car
    {
        private int year;
        private double mileage;
        private string colour;
        private string model;
        private string info;

        //constructor
        public Car()
        {
            year = 0;
            mileage = 0;
            colour = "";
            model = "";
        }

        //name properties
        public string Model
        {
            get { return model; }
            set { model = value; }
        }

        public string Colour
        {
            get { return colour; }
            set { colour = value; }
        }

        public double Mileage
        {
            get { return mileage; }
            set { mileage = value; }
        }

        public int Year
        {
            get { return year; }
            set { year = value; }
        }

        //returns string consisting of model, year, mileage, colour
        public string GetInfo(string sep)
        {
            sep = ": ";
            return model + sep + colour + sep + mileage.ToString("c") + sep + year.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `List<Car> list = new List<Car>() {myCar.Model, myCar.Mileage, myCar.Colour, myCar.Year};` - what exactly do you intended this to do? You tell it you are trying to create a list of `Car`, but are supplying the components of a `Car`, not an actual `Car` object.

Comment: You should assign values to the object you created.  For example  List<Car> list = new List<Car>() {myCar.Model = "Malibu", myCar.Mileage = 150, myCar.Colour = color.Red, myCar.Year = 2015};

Comment: start reading MSDN Documentation as well and understand the `.ToStrng()` Overloads https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I did not even look at your load/write methods that use the stream reader as you had no implementation there. If you want help on serialization please ask another question.*

Your problem is your syntax for your initializer is wrong. Here are valid ways you can instatiate an object. See [Object and Collection Initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) for more details.

```
Car myCar = new Car(); // no initializers
Car myCar = new Car(){Model = "Bently", Mileage = 1555, Colour = "Red", Year = 2015}; // with initializer
```

Examples with `List<Car>`

```
List<Car> list = new List<Car>(); // no initializers
List<Car> list = new List<Car>() {myCar} ; // with a car instance
List<Car> list = new List<Car>() {myCar1, myCar2, myCar3} ; // with car instances assuming these instances all exist
```

You can also combine them although its not very clean looking

```
List<Car> list = new List<Car>() {new Car(){Model = "Bently", Mileage = 1555, Colour = "Red", Year = 2015}} ; // with a car instance
```

On a side note you can convert your properties to [AutoProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) which can help clean up your code a little as well.

```
namespace Car_Management
{
    class Car
    {
        public Car()
        {
            Year = 0;
            Mileage = 0;
            Colour = "";
            Model = "";
        }

        //name properties
        public string Model {get;set;}
        public string Colour {get;set;}
        public double Mileage {get;set;}
        public int Year {get;set;}

        //returns string consisting of model, year, mileage, colour
        public string GetInfo(string sep)
        {
            sep = ": ";
            return model + sep + colour + sep + mileage.ToString("c") + sep + year.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your instantiation of the list is wrong.

```
public static void save(List<Car> fullList)
{
    Car myCar = new Car();
    List<Car> list = new List<Car>() {myCar.Model, myCar.Mileage, myCar.Colour, myCar.Year};

    StreamWriter outputFile;
    outputFile = File.CreateText("List.txt");
}
```

What you´re trying to do here is to instantiate a list of string, double, string etc.

What you should do is either: Create the car before-hand like this:

```
Car myCar = new Car();
myCar.Model = "Some Model";
myCar.Mileage = 0;
...

List<Car> list = new List<Car>();
list.add(myCar);
```

or as you tried:

```
List<Car> list = new List<Car>(){myCar};
```

or if you want to do it all in one go (NB: Messy and unreadable code):

```
List<Car> list = new List<Car(){new Car(){Model = "Some model", Mileage = 0, ... }}
```

Personally I prefer the first method since it's easier to read, and easier to dive into the code afterwards.

If you have several cars, you can do: `List<Car> list = new List<Car>(){car1, car2, car3};` AFTER creating the cars objects as shown above. Hope it helps.

You can read more here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/list

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is incorrect:

`Car myCar = new Car();
List<Car> list = new List<Car>() {myCar.Model, myCar.Mileage, myCar.Colour, myCar.Year};`

and I'm not sure what you're tring to do. If you're trying to create a list with a single car you should write:

`Car myCar = new Car(){ Model = "model1", Mileage = 23000, Colour = "green", Year = 2009 };
List<Car> list = new List<Car>();
list.Add(myCar);`

This will make the code compile. However there are other issues like the unused parameter `fullList` and you're creating a file "List.txt" and never writing to it.